# Relation between $SO(n)$ and rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, geometry, lie-groups, intuition

We often consider $SO(n)$ as the group of rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the sense that the usual action of $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by matrix multiplication can be interpreted as a rotation operation in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Although I've always used this fact, I never had an intuitive understanding of why is that.

Basically, we know that the linear transformation associated to a matrix $A$ is inner product preserving if and only if $A\in O(n)$. In truth, if $A\in O(n)$ then we know that $AA^T = I$ and hence

$$\langle Ax, Ay\rangle=\langle x, A^TA y\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle , \quad \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Furthermore, if $A$ is inner product preserving, then $A\in O(n)$. Then we have two possible choices, $\det(A) = +1$ and so $A\in SO(n)$ and $\det(A) = -1$ and $A\in O(n)\setminus SO(n)$.

In that case, an element of $SO(n)$ is simply one inner product preserving linear transformation, that is, which doesn't change angles nor lengths, and which has determinant $+1$.

Now, from this rigorous definition of the elements of $SO(n)$ how can one see that the elements of $SO(n)$ can be though of as rotation operators? Why rotation is related to the elements of that group and how can one arrive at the definition of $SO(n)$ in trying to define properly the group of rotations?

Comment: I guess I'm confused about the question. Rotations should be the operations which have a fixed center, do not flip orientation, and are rigid body transformations, which are precisely the properties used when defining $SO(n)$. Would you like a proof that such an operation can always be decomposed into a collection of 2D rotations around multiple planes (with one fixed axis in odd dimension)?

Comment: What I'm confused @RobertMastragostino, is how, this rigorous definition of rotations agrees with our intuitive picture of rotations, i.e., how to see that this definition makes the intuitive idea of rotations rigorous. Is the way to see this the decomposition which you are talking about?

Comment: @user1620696: (i) By "this rigorous definition of rotations", do you mean (something equivalent to) "orientation-preserving linear rigid motion/Euclidean isometry"? It's not clear to me from your post (or comment) what you take to be the definition: The geometric condition, or "an element of $SO(n)$". (ii) Presumably you're happy with things for $n = 2$ and $n = 3$, but note that many people's initial geometric intuition about "rotations" is substantially wrong if $n \geq 4$. Particularly, a four-dimensional rotation needn't be periodic.

Comment: What I'm taking to be the definition is "an element of $SO(n)$". I know that on higher dimensions things change and that's why we use rigorous definitions like the geometric condition which is equivalent as describing rotiations with elements from $SO(n)$. What I'm trying to understand, is how to, starting from the idea of rotations from $2$ and $3$ dimensions, motivate the rigorous definition (either the geometric condition or the "being an element of $SO(n)$" condition) which works in general.

Comment: I see...but your post outlines the argument that if $A \in SO(n)$, then the linear transformation $x \mapsto Ax$ is orientation-preserving (because $\det A = 1 > 0$), and preserves the Euclidean inner product, and therefore preserves distances between arbitrary pairs of points, i.e., is a Euclidean isometry. So, I'm still not sure what type of motivation you're seeking. When you think of rotations of the plane or of space, do you have a criterion in mind other than "orientation-preserving linear rigid motion"?

Comment: @AndrewDHwang, sorry but I think that unfortunatelly I wasn't able to expose what I'm trying to do in the question. What I've stated is the definition right? It works for any $n$ so it is a good definition. Now, when I think from just one intuitive point of view about rotations I think about "tilting a vector" with respect to some axis by some angle. This is how we usually do in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and characterize the rotation by one angle. I'm trying to see how starting from this intuitive view which works in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can motivate the actual rigorous definition which works in general.

Comment: I think in most stuff I have read, the only definition of rotation in R^n was precisely an isometry with determinant +1, i.e. Exactly an element of SO(n). I did see a reference once that demanded rotations to a act as the identity on a subspace of dimension n-2 so that it only moved two dimensions at once . I think the former definition is more natural..

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Neg}{\phantom{-}}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}$Perhaps the issue is to see that an orientation-preserving, distance-preserving transformation of $\Reals^{n}$ that fixes the origin $O$ (a common geometric definition of a "rotation about the origin") is precisely multiplication by an element of $SO(n)$. The following gives one formalization.

**Theorem**: Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer. If $T:\Reals^{n} \to \Reals^{n}$, then the following are equivalent.

1. $T$ is orientation-preserving, distance-preserving, and fixes the origin.
2. $T$ is an orientation-preserving, distance-preserving *linear* transformation.
3. There exists a matrix $A$ in $SO(n)$ such that $T(x) = Ax$ for all $x$ in $\Reals^{n}$.

*Proof*: (1. implies 2.) Consider first the plane case ($n = 2$). If $T_{0}$ is a distance-preserving plane transformation that fixes $O$, $\Basis_{1} = (1, 0)$, and $\Basis_{2} = (0, 1)$, then $T$ fixes the line $\ell_{1}$ through $O$ and $\Basis_{1}$ (because every point on $\ell_{1}$ is uniquely determined by its distances to $O$ and $\Basis_{1}$). Consequently, $T_{0}$ fixes every point of the plane, namely, is the identity transformation (since every point of the plane is uniquely determined by its distance to $\ell_{1}$ and its distance to $\Basis_{2}$).

Now assume $T$ is an orientation-preserving, distance-preserving plane transformation that fixes $0$. There exists a real number $\theta$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
T(\Basis_{1}) &= (\cos\theta, \sin\theta), \\
T(\Basis_{2}) &= \bigl(\cos(\theta + \tfrac{\pi}{2}), \sin(\theta + \tfrac{\pi}{2})\bigr)
  = (-\sin\theta, \cos\theta).
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}
$$
Indeed, every point at unit distance from $O$ has the form $(\cos\phi, \sin\phi)$ for some real $\phi$, and if $T(\Basis_{1}) = (\cos\phi, \sin\phi)$, then the fact $T$ is distance-preserving implies $T(\Basis_{2}) = \pm(-\sin\phi, \cos\phi)$; choose $\theta = \phi$ or $\theta = \phi - \frac{\pi}{2}$ so that (1) holds.

If $R_{\theta}$ denotes rotation by $\theta$ about the origin, then $R_{\theta}^{-1} \circ T$ is distance-preserving and fixes $O$, $\Basis_{1}$, and $\Basis_{2}$, and is therefore the identity; this means $T = R_{\theta}$. This completes the proof of (1. implies 2.) for the case $n = 2$.

A similar argument works for $n > 2$; the fact that $T$ is orientation-preserving is required in order to pick a special orthogonal matrix $A$ so that $A^{-1} \circ T$ fixes the origin and all the standard basis vectors.

(2. implies 1. is obvious.)

(2. if and only if 3.) In the body of the post. (A linear transformation $T(x) = Ax$ preserves distances if and only if $\Brak{Ax, Ay} = \Brak{x, y}$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $\Reals^{n}$, if and only if $A^{T}A = I_{n}$, and is orientation-preserving if and only if $\det A = 1$.)

---

Remarks about rotations of $\Reals^{n}$ for $n \geq 4$.

- A "fundamental rotation" of $\Reals^{n}$ (this term is not standard to my knowledge) fixes a linear subspace of dimension $(n - 2)$ and rotates the ($2$-dimensional) orthogonal complement just like an ordinary planar rotation. That is, the rotations most nearly generalizing one's planar and spatial intuition have an $(n - 2)$-dimensional "axis".
- If $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are oriented orthogonal planes in $\Reals^{4}$, and if $\alpha$ and $\theta$ are real, there is a rotation $T$ of $\Reals^{4}$ that rotates $P_{1}$ by $\theta$ and rotates $P_{2}$ by $\alpha\theta$. If $\alpha$ is irrational, the one-parameter subgroup of $SO(4)$ containing $T$, which in a suitable basis comprises the set of matrices
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 & 0 \\
  \sin\theta & \Neg\cos\theta & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \cos(\alpha\theta) & -\sin(\alpha\theta) \\
  0 & 0 & \sin(\alpha\theta) & \Neg\cos(\alpha\theta) \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  is an irrational winding on a torus; in particular, this one-parameter subgroup of rotations is not compact. Kinetically, if you set a pair of orthogonal planes in $\Reals^{4}$ turning at constant, incommensurable angular speeds, the planes never return to their starting configuration. Analogous phenomena occur in $\Reals^{n}$ with $n > 4$.
- [Euler's rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem) generalizes to odd-dimensional spaces: For every rotation $T$ of $\Reals^{2n+1}$, there exists a line through the origin that is fixed pointwise by $T$. The proof is the same as for the $3$-dimensional case: The characteristic polynomial of $A$ has odd degree, hence at least one real root, every real eigenvalue is either $+1$ or $-1$, and because $\det T = 1$, at least one eigenvalue is $+1$.